# Show how many times values are in an array

Tags: php

The php code below displays the country location of the IPs stored in a database and outputs it in an HTML table. As is, it creates a long list of the country code for each individual IP.

For example...

US
US
MX
US

What I would like to do is, rather than create a long list of each individual item, display the number of times an item shows up in the array. Using the example above...

country frequency

US 3 
MX 1

How would I implement this? Here's the full code...

```
require_once("geoip.inc");
$gi = geoip_open("GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);


include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'connect.php'); 

/* Performing SQL query */
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM the_ips LIMIT 100")
 or die(mysql_error());

 echo "<table>";
 echo "<td><strong>Country</strong></td><td><strong>Frequency</strong></td></tr>";

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
     {
      $ip = $info['ip_address'];
      $country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $ip);
      $countrylist = array($country_code);
      $frequency = array_count_values($countrylist);

      echo "<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>".$country_code."</td><td style='width: 100px;'>".$frequency."</td></tr>";
     }
 echo "</table>";
 geoip_close($gi);
```

I need to assign `$frequency` and remove rows that include duplicate "Country" value, but not sure how to do this. As is, $frequency returns "Array" when I was hoping for a number (i.e. US 3).

Comment: http://php.net/array_count_values

Comment: If that's a string, use `substr_count`, or `str_word_count`

Comment: To clarify... The ip is stored in the database. The code above gets the ips, checks the ip against IPs stored in the GeoIP.dat file, and matches the appropriate country code to the ip. When I use array_county_values, it returns 1 for each item even if it shows up multiple times. I think it's checking the ip, when I need to check the frequency of the Country Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) for that

Imagine this simple example:

```
$colors = array('red', 'green', 'red', 'blue');
var_dump(array_count_values($colors));
```

What gives you:

```
array(3) {
  'red' =>
  int(2)
  'green' =>
  int(1)
  'blue' =>
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added `array_count_values` and got Array ( [US] => 1 ) Array ( [US] => 1 ) Array ( [MX] => 1 ) Array ( [US] => 1 ). Looking for something like US = 3 MX = 1.

Comment: Can you add a var_dump of the array to question?

Comment: array(1) { ["US"]=> int(1) } array(1) { ["US"]=> int(1) } array(1) { ["US"]=> int(1) } array(1) { ["UK"]=> int(1) } array(1) { ["US"]=> int(1) }

Comment: Please post the code that populates the array to your question. (Note 'question', not in the comments)

Comment: updated question with the code